# Data points to Colored Map

Tags: google-maps

I have a set of Latlng coordinates that I want to place on a Google Map, but instead of the usual markers, I want to create an overlay where a higher density of these latlng points will create a redder color overlay, while a lower density will give a greener overlay, everywhere in between will be a shade in between red and green. How can I achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to [build heat map](http://www.google.com/support/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1152262) with data stored in Google Fusion Tables.

Also, have a look at this question from GIS SE:

[How could I turn my data into a heatmap / intensity map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16530/how-could-i-turn-my-data-into-a-heatmap-intensity-map)